# Jqgrid pager text vertical alignment

Tags: jqgrid

I'm using the Jqgrid in my ASP.NET MVC 4 application and for some reasons, the pager text (Page X of X) seems to be aligned to the bottom, although I tried to change the CSS (ui.grid.css) to align middle/top.  This only happens with IE9.  It displays correctly with Firefox.  Has anyone had similar issue?

I wanted to post the image but the spam prevention mechanism on this site does not allow it.

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured out what is causing the problem.  It is the Document Mode in the IE.  It was set as "IE7 standards".  Setting it to "IE8 or IE9 standards" fixed the issue.